# "Nice to have" terms in a Sunspot search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I want to do a search in Sunspot that basically says this:

- MUST contain one of "ruby" or "rails"
- IF it contains one of "contract", "freelance" or "part-time", that's an added bonus, but none of these terms are necessary

I'm aware of `boost` but all the examples seem to use `with(:whatever => true)`, which is not what I want. What I'm doing seems pretty simple and I would imagine pretty common, so I'm super confused.

How can I do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

This is hacky, but it should work

If all your searches are on the same field, you can sacrifice tokenization and have:

In your model:

```
searchable do
    string :yourfield
    integer :id # this is a trick, you'll see
    # more conditions
end
```

And for your search:

```
search = Yourmodel.search
    with(:yourfield).any_of(['ruby'],['rails'])
    any_of do
        with(:yourfield).any_of(['contract'],['freelance'],['part-time'])
        with(:id).greater_than_or_equal_to(1) #all fields!!
    end
end
```